# C# - Passing functions (with arguments) as arguments of a function

Tags: c#, function, generics, parameters

I need to create a function, that will take another functions (always different quantity of them). Can someone help me please?

Function DoThisFunction will have different types and quantity of parameters.
there can be different number of condition functions.

I'll try to show it here:

```
bool MyFunction(condition1(args), condition2(args), condition3(args), ... , DoThisFunction(args))
{
    ...
    if (condition1(int x) == true && condition2(int x, string C) == 5)
    {
        DoThisFunction(par1, par2, par3 ...);
        return true;
    }
}

bool condition1(int x)
{
if (x>5)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int condition2(int x, string C)
{
....
return par1;
}
```

etc...

Then I need to call:

```
bool z = MyFunction(condition1(int x)==true, condition2(int x, string C)==5, DoThisFunction(par1, anotherArguments ...))
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I have the feeling you are going in the wrong way.

Comment: Why can't you simply on the outside simply do: `if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) DoThisFunction(...);` ? Why do you need to abstract away the actual call to everything? Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Cause the arguments of the "conditions" are calculated within the MyFunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest another approach for your code.
Maybe, you can keep a separated list with all the functions you need to verify, and run each method inside a very simple loop (foreach), in this case:

- the code will be very friendly (easy to understand)
- better maintainability
- you can review less code and add more functionality (for instance, you may inject some code and just add another Func<> into your List<>)

Please, take a look at the following example:

```
static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assertions = new List<Func<object[], bool>>
        {
            Assertion1,
            Assertion2,
            Assertion3
        };

        var yourResult = Assert(assertions, 1, "1", true);
        Console.WriteLine(yourResult); // returns "True" in this case
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool Assert(IEnumerable<Func<object[], bool>> assertions, params object[] args)
    {
        // the same as
        // return assertions.Aggregate(true, (current, assertion) => current & assertion(args));

        var result = true;

        foreach (var assertion in assertions)
            result = result & assertion(args);

        return result;
    }

    private static bool Assertion1(params object[] args)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) == 1;
    }

    private static bool Assertion2(params object[] args)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
    }

    private static bool Assertion3(params object[] args)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(args[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to generic for your problem.

For checking preconditions before executing methods have a look at [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use functor like the following:

```
private bool MyFunction(Func<int, bool> condition1, Func<int,string,int> condition2, Func<int,string,int, int> doThisFunction, int x, string str)
{
    if (condition1(x) && condition2(x, str) == 5)
        return doThisFunction(x, str, x) == 10;
    return false;
}
```

Then call this function in your code like the below:

```
MyFunction(x => x > 5 ? true : false, (x, C) => C.Length == x * 5 ? 5 : C.Length, 
           (x, str, y) =>
           {
               if (x + y > str.Length)
                   return 5;
               else if (x * y > 5)
                   return 10;
               else
                   return 15;
           }, 10, "Csharp");
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising with some overloading (cause the function MyFunction needs to take every time different number of arguments), but I have no idea how this "lambda" (=>) thing works.

Comment: You can see more details about lambda expressions in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I know, I'm trying to understand it for some time now, but I guess that's way too much for me yet.

Comment: I basically want to create my own loop, only if I know how loops like "for" are made. You can do within the loop anything you want, call functions as you want. I need basically the same.